# What Are The Accepted Keys for NSTextView.typingAttributes?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

In Swift on macOS, I have the following Text View and want to set the font size of text that is entered into it, like so:

```
myTextView.typingAttributes = ["Unknown" : NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)]
```

I am currently unable to do this, as I do not know, nor could a find on the 
[Apple Documentation Page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview), what the accepted keys are for typingAttributes.

Does anyone know what these are, or where to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the supported attribute names in the [documentation for `NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1652619-character_attributes) under [Character Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring). For the font, you would use `NSFontAttributeName`.

Comment: Thanks for the correct documentation, though NSFontAttributeName yields the following error: [_SwiftValue fontForAppearance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue with the bridge from Swift to Objective-C. Maybe you need to unwrap the optional returned from `NSFont`'s failable initializer.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was. Coming from iOS, I've yet to receive an error with an optional that didn't explicitly state that the optional was at fault (though now understanding the issue, I do see what this error message meant.)